# Why is Telegram much more popular than Signal, which is, according to everything I've read, more secure?

Tags: mobile

I'm disregarding apps such as WhatsApp and Viber, because I assume majority of their users aren't particularly concerned about privacy, so it's not surprising they have more users.

But how is it possible that, according to Google Play Store, Telegram has **hundred times** the installs that Signal has, even though Signal is older and, according to everything I've read, more secure?

Is it simply marketing? Why isn't Open Whisper doing more to increase Signal's popularity?

Comment: This question seems to be more about psychology or marketing than about information security.

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer marketing questions.

Comment: TL;DR: Telegram has great marketing department und a bad security department and Signal has great security people but a mediocre marketing department.

Comment: just because something is better or has higher quality it's not more popular.